# Android Studio: ERROR: The modules ['@react-native-community_cameraroll', 'react-native-community_cameraroll'] point to the same directory

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react native app that I'm trying to run on Android. However, every time I try to load Android Studio, it complains that I have a duplicate import.

When I check, I can only find one of the imports it complains about:

```
client master % ag react-native-community_cameraroll
android/app/build.gradle
212:    compile project(':@react-native-community_cameraroll')

android/settings.gradle
2:include ':@react-native-community_cameraroll'
3:project(':@react-native-community_cameraroll').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cameraroll/android')
```

How would I fix this issue?

Not sure if this matters at all but here's my package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.0.0-beta.41",
    "@bugsnag/expo": "^6.5.0",
    "@eva-design/eva": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "@expo/react-native-action-sheet": "^3.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/cameraroll": "^2.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "2.2.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.6",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/admob": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.2.4",
    "@react-navigation/compat": "^5.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.8",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "^5.0.0",
    "@ui-kitten/eva-icons": "^5.0.0",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.5",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.8",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.13",
    "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.19",
    "apollo-link-error": "^1.1.12",
    "apollo-upload-client": "^12.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bugsnag-react-native": "^2.23.7",
    "expo": "^37.0.0",
    "expo-blur": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-camera": "~8.2.0",
    "expo-constants": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-file-system": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-localization": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-media-library": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-notifications": "^0.1.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-updates": "^0.2.2",
    "final-form": "^4.18.2",
    "graphql": "^14.6.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.1",
    "i18n-js": "^3.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "lottie-ios": "^3.1.3",
    "lottie-react-native": "^3.3.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-range": "^4.0.2",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.3",
    "react-dom": "16.9.0",
    "react-final-form": "^6.3.0",
    "react-native": "~0.61.5",
    "react-native-appearance": "~0.3.3",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.259.0",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-drag-sort": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.1.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.15.0",
    "react-native-iap": "^4.4.9",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^2.2.27",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-share": "^3.7.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^11.0.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0-nightly.5",
    "react-native-ui-kitten": "^4.3.2",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.9.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.3.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.9.0",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.5",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.2",
    "victory-native": "^32.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "babel-jest": "~25.2.6",
    "jest": "~25.2.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "~16.9.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.11",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.60.22",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^8.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "apollo-client": "2.6.8"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird, it seems OK,

remove the .iml and re-import the project.
Let us know if this does the Job!

Comment: Hey. Should I delete the `appname.iml` or `app/app.iml` file?

Comment: Remove the iml file in each module